# Unable to get remote maven artifactory from tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, drools

I defined rules in drools workbench and able to fire those rules successfully using simple java class.
I need to provide rest api to fire these ruels. so i created webservices project and deployed in tomcat.

It is giving `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find KieModule`

I solved this problem initially by placing settings.xml in m2 with simple java class.

but now i am getting this problem in tomcat. It seems tomcat is unable to use maven settings.xml

Any solution plz..

Comment: Can you provide more details , are you deploying a REST client to Drools API ? Did you include the JARS for Drools and KIE classes  in tomcat ?

Comment: Yes @RamachandranGA i have added required jar files in tomcat ... actually i need to define rules in workbench and from there i need to get those remote rules through programming and providing rest api to end user to fire these rules.